# What is scalar product between two spaces?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, optimal-control

[image]

This is a snapshot from a book on Optimal control and partial differential equations.

My doubts are:-

> **Is the D'($\Omega$) space metrizable with the pseudo-topology?**

> **What is the formal definition of scalar product between spaces namely D($\Omega$) and D'($\Omega$)?**

> **Why is the scalar product between spaces given by equation 1 like that?**

**Notation**

$\Omega$ is an open set of n dimensional Euclidean space and $\Gamma$ is it's boundary.